# function return NaN

Tags: r

I dont understand why the below function return NaN even the answer shouldn't be NaN.
I have tried to search similar question but most of them in other programming language that i couldn't understand.

Code:

```
a0 = 1.5; a1 = 0.4; b1 = 0.3; g1= 0.7
nu = rep(0,1)
h.new = rep(0,1)
ddp = rep(0,1)

nu[1]=0

h.new[1] = a0/(1-a1-b1)
ddp[1] = 0.5*log(g1)- g1*h.new[1] + 
  nu[1]*(log(nu[1])-1) - log(factorial(nu[1]))+(g1)*nu[1]* 
  (1+log(h.new[1]/nu[1]))
```

This is the output:

```
###> ddp
###[1] NaN
```

Then I do manual calculation, clearly show that ddp is not NaN:

```
###h.new = 1.5/(1-0.4-0.3) = 5

###ddp 
###= 0.5*log(0.7)- (0.7)*(5) + 
###(0)*(log(0)-1) - log(0!)+(0.7)*(0)* 
###(1+log(5/0))

###= 0.5*log(0.7)- (0.7)*(5)

###= -3.6783
```

I did know for sum() function, na.rm=TRUE could ommit all the missing value,
but in this case, how to modify the code to make it return to the correct answer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to take `log(0)`, or `5/0`?

Comment: hi @user2357112, the given data (nu[1]) is 0, in the whole dataset, there is some data with value and some are 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general `0*Inf` gives `NaN` in R: the computer doesn't/can't know how you want to take the limit.  If you know that you want these limits to be zero, you can specify how your computation works in the special case `nu==0`:

```
term3 <- if (nu==0) 0 else nu*(log(nu)-1)
term5 <- if (nu==0) 0 else g1*nu*(1+log(h.new/nu))
ddp = 0.5*log(g1)-
    g1*h.new + 
    term3 - 
    log(factorial(nu))+
    term5
```

You could do this slightly more generally with a `zprod` function:

```
zprod <- function(x,y) {
     if (x==0) 0 else x*y
}
ddp = 0.5*log(g1)- g1*h.new + 
      zprod(nu,log(nu)-1) - log(factorial(nu))+
      g1*zprod(nu,1+log(h.new/nu))
```

Answer (score 2):

`nu[1]` is 0 and the log of 0 is undefined. R evaluates `log(0)` as `-Inf`
Then you have `log(5/0)` - what is 5/0? It's undefined. So you have lots of undefined values which will create an overall undefined result. As noted in Ben's answer, the `NaN` is created when you multiply 0 by `Inf` or `-Inf`

However, even if these two elements were to resolve to 0, the code you've written would evaluate to -3.68, not -0.52. So, you're doing something wrong by hand.

Comment: well, `log(5/0)` is also `Inf`. You don't get `NaN` until you try to multiply infinite values by zero ...

Comment: That's true. I guess I was mostly trying to highlight the inclusion of two undefined numbers which R is friendly enough to define as -Inf and Inf but should probably both be NaN on their own. There's no way this is evaluating to -0.52

Comment: @Mark, thanks for your remind, after recalculate i have made correction to -3.68.